# Receiving "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory" while trying to install lxml

Tags: python

I am attempting to install lxml using "pip install lxml" in my terminal, and receiving the C1083 error. I have seen similar posts, and based on those suggested answers attempted the following:

Downloading .whl files from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). I am using a 32-bit version of Python 3.8 using Windows 10 and attempt:

`pip install C:\folders\lxml-4.5.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`

however it claims it is not a supported wheel on this platform. As a check, I used every lxml from the site, with the exact same error. I then attempt to use

`pip install lxml --extra-index-url=https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml`

which results in the C1083 error as well.

I am aware that I need libxml/xpath.h, but for some reason none of the wheel files are being accepted. Please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide. How can I go about installing lxml?

Comment: How was your python installed?

Comment: I initially installed it via Anaconda3. However, that wasn't the current 3.8 version. I am having some difficulty remember how exactly I updated to 3.8. If there's a way for me to find out I would be happy to look into it.

Comment: Doesn't anaconda have libraries also?

Comment: I'm not confident I know exactly what library means for Python, but I believe it does. It did come with lxml, but isn't being recognized when I try to install python-docx, which is the module I'm actually trying to install, but which depends upon lxml2.

Comment: I think you would have better results with installing python packages with C extensions the same way you installed python. So either install an official python and then install official lxml package, or do everything through anaconda.